# Blender not importing openings from doors or windows from IFC file

Tags: export, add-on, import, error

I want to import an IFC file exported from REVIT, using the BlenderBIM add-on.

Once in Blender, some openings (doors and windows) are not imported, and window and door families are imported embeded in walls, while some openings are imported without a problem with the window and door in place. I have to say that it is always the same openings that are or aren't imported, meaning that it is not a random problem. In some cases, the opening for a door family in a specific wall is imported, but the opening of the same door copied in a different wall, is not.

I have checked the IFC file using a IFC viewer and all the openings are there. Perhaps some setting during the import process that I'm missing?

[image: View of model on each version]

Console:

```
Done creating geometry
Creating meshified products :: 3.45
Relating openings :: 0.01
Placing objects in spatial tree :: 0.05
Add project to scene :: 0.00
Info: Removed 4 vertice(s)
Mesh cleaning :: 0.66
Setting default context :: 0.00
Import finished in 4.91 seconds
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_291\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1493 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '0' matches no enum in 'BIMRootProperties', '', 'ifc_predefined_type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_291\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1493 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '0' matches no enum in 'BIMRootProperties', '', 'ifc_predefined_type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_291\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1493 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '0' matches no enum in 'BIMRootProperties', '', 'ifc_predefined_type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_291\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1493 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '0' matches no enum in 'BIMRootProperties', '', 'ifc_predefined_type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_291\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1493 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '0' matches no enum in 'BIMRootProperties', '', 'ifc_predefined_type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_291\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1493 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '0' matches no enum in 'BIMRootProperties', '', 'ifc_predefined_type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_291\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1493 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '0' matches no enum in 'BIMRootProperties', '', 'ifc_predefined_type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_291\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1493 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '0' matches no enum in 'BIMRootProperties', '', 'ifc_predefined_type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_291\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1493 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '0' matches no enum in 'BIMRootProperties', '', 'ifc_predefined_type'
Info: Deleted 1 object(s)
```

Comment: Hello, could you check what is printed on the console after importing the model ? Go to Window > Toggle system console

Comment: Hi Gorgious, I've added the info from the console. Many thanks

Comment: There seems to be 9 errors related to converting ifc types, does it match the number of faulty objects ?

Comment: It preety much does... doors and windows that I can see on Revit and IFC viewer, but not on Blender.

Answer (score 2):

From memory, this was a bug when I was attempting to get better native handling of voids. When bringing IFC elements with voids into Blender, it may either be applied prior to the Blender mesh generation, or dynamically using Blender boolean modifiers. The former is good because it uses a system called OpenCascade, which has some tailored code to handle exact voids quite well. The latter is also good because it is easy to modify and see the results in real time, with the tradeoff that it may cause problems like you see above.

This bug has since been fixed, but your workaround in the IFC4 reference view applies the voids during the Revit IFC export time, so that would also give you a successful result.

Answer (score 1):

After painful hours of trial and error, I found the solution (or at least the problem, to some extent).

The problem comes from the way the file is exported to IFC format from Revit. Even though on the IFC viewer everything looked fine, there's something on Revit that does make a difference when exporting: the IFC version.

The version I had set was IFC 2x3 Coordination View 2.0, because I understood it's very reliable and because it exports objects, if not with textures, at least with material names assigned, which makes applying textures on Blender very easy.

However, there were issues with walls and opennings. In some cases, the opening was imported properly, in other cases it wasn't.

Now, a side note about this: The openings were actually imported, but they didn't go all the way through the wall. I tried playing with the width of wall and window and door families, but I never got a consistent result and was running out of time (an patience!)

The IFC version that imported the openings and all elements without a problem, was IFC4 Reference View, which I've heard is not as widely accepted as IFC 2, but it worked for me. Downside is that objects are imported without material names assigned, BUT, the material names list is imported.

I'm moving from there and assigning materials object by object, since it was more important for me to have walls with proper openings.

If somebody has a better solution, do say!